# Fragment cover full activity but button over activity is still clickable.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

How to disable an activity coding when a fragment is replace it?
Activity programming is running behind and also clickable.

Comment: share some code and explain more about the problem, using Fragments meant to create a screen (activity) from several parts (Fragments) so what you are explaining is not a problem, if you want, you can view 1 Fragment in an empty activity so no other Views will be displayed.

Comment: I want to use that fragment over activity that's containing some buttons and edittext... But I solve this problem by INVISIBLE the layout on that activity when i am using fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INVISIBLE the layout when using FRAGMENT over an activity.
That way fragment will not access the activity layout at all.

Answer (score 1):

Even better solution is to make fragment's root layout "clickable=true" , focusable = "true" & background="some color"